# Finding C in $A = BC + CB^T$

Tags: calculus, matrices, solution-verification

I am struggling to solve a Lyapunov equation $A = BC + CB^T$ , where

$$
A = \begin{bmatrix} a_1 & 0 \\ 0  & a_2 \end{bmatrix}, B = \begin{bmatrix} b & c \\ c  & b \end{bmatrix}
$$
and C is some two-dimensional covariance matrix that I would like to find.

**My calculation:**

$$
\Rightarrow A = BC + CB^T
$$
Then I am trying to define the equation in terms of C  so I tried something like this;
$$
\Rightarrow B^{-1}A (B^T)^{-1} = B^{-1}BC (B^T)^{-1} + B^{-1}CB^T  (B^T)^{-1} \\
            B^{-1}A (B^T)^{-1} = C (B^T)^{-1} + B^{-1}C \\
            B^{-1}A (B)^{-1} = C (B)^{-1} + B^{-1}C
$$

(multiplying inverse values to try and have $C$ on one side)then from here I can't figure out how to get to the $C$.

Could you point out what I am missing here?

Comment: Are you trying to find all solutions or just one?

Comment: Hi @N.S. just one. So its the limit case of the covariance matrix.

Answer (score 2):

These are all $2\times 2$ matrices so it won't be hard to solve component-wise. Let $C$ be

$$ C=\begin{bmatrix} \gamma_{11}&\gamma_{12}\\\gamma_{21}&\gamma_{22} \end{bmatrix} $$

then when we multiply we get something like

$$ BC + CB = \begin{bmatrix} 2b\gamma_{11}+c\gamma_{12}+c\gamma_{21}&
2b\gamma_{12}+c\gamma_{11}+c\gamma_{22}
\\2b\gamma_{21}+c\gamma_{11}+c\gamma_{22}&2b\gamma_{22}+c\gamma_{12}+c\gamma_{21} \end{bmatrix} $$

which implies that

$$ \begin{align}  a_1 = 2b\gamma_{11}+c\gamma_{12}+c\gamma_{21}\\
0=2b\gamma_{12}+c\gamma_{11}+c\gamma_{22}
\\0=2b\gamma_{21}+c\gamma_{11}+c\gamma_{22}\\a_2=2b\gamma_{22}+c\gamma_{12}+c\gamma_{21}  \end{align}$$

which is four equations and four unknowns.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Let $$C= \begin{bmatrix} x & y \\
z & t \end{bmatrix}$$

Then
$$
A = BC + CB^T \leftrightarrow \\
\begin{bmatrix} a_1 & 0 \\ 0  & a_2 \end{bmatrix}=  \begin{bmatrix} b & c \\ c  & b \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x & y \\
z & t \end{bmatrix}  +\begin{bmatrix} x & y \\
z & t \end{bmatrix}  \begin{bmatrix} b & c \\ c  & b \end{bmatrix} \Leftrightarrow  \\
\begin{bmatrix} a_1 & 0 \\ 0  & a_2 \end{bmatrix}=  \begin{bmatrix} 2bx+cz+cy & 2by+ct+cx \\ cx+ct+2bz  & cy+cz+2bt \end{bmatrix}
$$

This is a system of 4 linear equations. This is made simpler by the fact that the 0 entries give
$$
by=bz=-c(t+x)
$$
which reduces the problem to $b=0$ or $y=z$.

**P.S.** If you know that $b \neq 0$ then $y=z$ which means you get the system:
$$
bx+cy =\frac{a_1}{2} \\
2by+ct+cx =0 \\
cy+bt=\frac{a_2}{2}
$$

This can be easily solved, you can for example apply CRamer's rule.

Comment: Hi, N.S  in my case It would have to be $y=z$.

Comment: @user4933 In which case you have a linear system of 3 equations with 3 unknowns.